# Can anyone tell me of there is a web based Biztalk business rule engine composer?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-rule-engine

Was wondering if anyone can anyone tell me of there is a web-based Biztalk business rule engine composer???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing out in the field that I've seen for a web based tool for BRE.  The rules engine was originally built outside of the BizTalk team and hasn't been updated since 2004 and still has numerous 'quirks' still in it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like that from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Authoring experience of BRE should provide solution for both web and windows form. Unfortunately BizTalk did not provide that.

Well if you want a BRE that supports web authoring as well as execution you can have a look at this post http://www.flexrule.com/archives/business-rules-web/